# Xcode doesn't recognize the word "class"

Tags: c++, xcode, class

I'm trying to create a simple c++ class in Xcode.

i'm just typing:

> class Sculpture {
>
> ...
>
> };

and it doesn't let me do it, I get two errors:

> Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?
>
> Expected ';' after top level declarator

Both on the same line of the class declaration.

i've tried to make a new file and it did not help.

the most strange part is that i have another 2-3 c++ classes working just fine

but they where not created by me so i'm not sure what are the differences.

Did anyone see something like that before?

Comment: What's your file extension? Did you forget a `;` after a class definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you declare your class in .h file which is included in non-c++ compilation unit. So, check your .h file is included only in .cpp/.cc or .mm files, not in .c or .m.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that the source file is being compiled as C, not C++. The language is determined by file extension; make sure it's `.cc`, `.cpp` or `.cxx` for plain C++, or `.mm` for Objective C++.